# Time Complexity of the makeEmpty() of the Top-Down splay tree

Tags: c++, data-structures, big-o, time-complexity, splay-tree

In [this implementation of a splay tree](http://users.cis.fiu.edu/~weiss/dsaa_c%2B%2B3/code/SplayTree.h), the listed time complexity of the `makeEmpty()` function (which removes all elements) is O(n). It is implemented as follows:

```
 while( !isEmpty( ) )
 {
     findMax( );        // Splay max item to root
     remove( root->element );
 }
```

Given that both `findMax` and `remove` might have time complexity proportional to the height of the tree, why will this take O(n) time in the worst-case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three words:  The Sequential Access Theorem.

http://www.wseas.us/e-library/conferences/cairns2001/papers/632.pdf

Because the above loop repeatedly removes the maximum value, it effectively visits all of the elements in sequence, and so I'm pretty certain the sequential access theorem applies.